# How to create multiple of the same object then put into an array

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object

Still new to object oriented programming but I am trying to figure out how to create multiple objects of the same type of object and put them into an array. So basically what I am trying to do is there is a file I am reading in which says the number of objects that need to be created and the position on the screen. Once that is read in I need to create that many number of the object and place each one at that position on the screen. I already have all the methods working fine for placing the object on the screen at the position given and reading the file and getting the text from the file to get the coordinates out of the file.The only problem I can't figure out is how to make multiple of the same object easily. So if someone could help that would be great. Basically if the file I read says 2 I need to make 2 of the object. If the object says 5 I need to make 5. I have tried looking around for other posts like this but can't seem to find any for making multiple objects.

I was thinking about just creating a loop that runs x amount of times to create how ever many I want but then wouldn't they all have the same name and the previous would just be written over?

Currently I only know how to make multiple objects of the same by naming them each something different and then putting them into an array.

```
     Dog dog1 = new Dog(90,5);
     Dog dog2 = new Dog(23,39);
     Dog dog3 = new Dog(87,65);
     Dog dog4 = new Dog(4,15);
     Dog[] dogPositions = new Dog[]{dog1,dog2,dog3,dog4};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to go back to the basicd of array and loop.  Do you know that you can access array elements by usind index, such as `dogPositions[0]` gives the first item of the array?  You need to refer to the documentation of whatever programming language you are using.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454953/c-sharp-making-classes-in-a-for-loop

Comment: I am aware of how to access indexes of an array using a for loop. I just posted this showing what I am using for testing my code right now. All I am asking is how to make multiple objects of the same type all at once. I want to be able to create x amount of the object.

Comment: `wouldn't they all have the same name and the previous would just be written over` no that doesn't happen. In the loop you need to create new object every time and set its properties and add that object to the array. And rest you know about how you access the array elements by using index. You need to try that and come back if you face any issue in that.

Comment: Alright that's all I needed to know. I didn't know that creating an object in a loop and then assigning it straight away to an array would work. That's all I needed. Sorry for frustrating you.

Comment: No... It didn't frustrate me... But this question wouldn't be in place if things were tried and figured first before looking for an opinion.. Anyways happy to help... Happy Coding...

Answer (score 0):

We can create objects in loop and assign it directly to the array like

```
for(i=0;i<=x,i++++) {
dogpositions[i]=new Dog(z,y);
}
```

Using these you can create multiple objects of the same type at once and insert it into array

**I hope it helps**

Answer (score 0):

```
Dog[] dogPositions = new Dog[4]; // number of object
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
  dogPositions[i]=new Dog(90,5);
}
```